# Расчет расстояний между городами

Tags: php, javascript

Есть задача - нужно сделать расчет расстояния между двумя городами, для водителей грузовиков, но нужно не просто вывести километраж, а еще все населенные пункты между ними, а также погоду в этих населенных пунктах. Я точно знаю, что такое можно сделать, так как уже видел в интернете, но сейчас не могу найти ссылку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм решения этой задачи?

Comment: Случайно не это http://mazorati.ru/archives/324 ?

Comment: В общем надо копать в сторону Google Maps API, конкретно 
Distance Matrix Service. Пример http://jsfiddle.net/XRMxf/

Answer (score 3):

Сервис только развивается.
Пока API слабовато но будем надеяться...

> http://calc-api.ru/apipages:CitiesDistance/

Answer (score 2):

```
mapDisplayRoute = function(){
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var start = markerStart.position;
        var end = markerEnd.position;
        var request = { origin:start, destination:end, travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                myRoute.distance.text = myRoute.distance.text.replace(',','');
                miles = myRoute.distance.text.split(' ');
                miles = miles[0];

                start = myRoute.start_address                   
                end = myRoute.end_address

                console.log(miles + ' - ' + start + ' - ' + end);
                setDirectionsInfo(miles, start, end);
                markerStart.setMap(null);
                markerEnd.setMap(null);
                delete(markerStart);
                delete(markerEnd);
                markerStartExists = false;
                markerEndExists = false;
            }
            });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }
```

этот код вроде ложит на картe маршрут, расчитанный по двум точка(маркерам) , мне тут нужно было только расстояние, но промежуточные точки можно посмотреть вроде в response

Comment: погоду по точке можно получить, ну если точки будут в формате страна - город то нужно ище через геокодер прогнать что б получить их координаты, а дальше воспользуйтесь любым бесплатным апи , думаю их куча

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей задачи можно использовать например Postgis.

Пример запроса:

```
demo=# SELECT p1.name,p2.name,ST_Distance_Sphere(p1.the_geom,p2.the_geom) FROM cities AS p1, cities AS p2 WHERE p1.id > p2.id;
      name       |      name       | st_distance_sphere
-----------------+-----------------+--------------------
 London, Ontario | London, England |   5875766.85191657
 East London,SA  | London, England |   9789646.96784908
 East London,SA  | London, Ontario |   13892160.9525778
 (3 строки)
```

Данный запрос возвращает расстояние между городами в метрах.